# How to import ImgAug 0.4.0 in Colab?

Tags: python, import, google-colaboratory, data-augmentation

I would like to use some augmentation techniques of the package imgaug 0.4.0 (link: https://github.com/aleju/imgaug) in Google Colab. Currently, there is version 0.2.9 imported by default. Is there a way to import 0.4.0?

I already tried to install it using `!pip install imgaug`.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip uninstall imgaug`  unistall current version of imgaug
`pip install imgaug`
install latest version of imgaug
or
`pip install img==version`

it is not recomended because other library depend on that specifc version will stop working best way to do this is by creating virtual environment so it not mess with other libraries

Comment: Ok, but then this version (0.4.0) is only installed in this specific notebook or is it installed by default when I am using Colab?

Comment: it will applicable only for specifc notebook and till the session is running once session will restart/terminated everything will restore to default you have to do this again

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import spesific version like 0.4.0, you can use following commands. Before installing the version we need to uninstall the current one.

```
!pip uninstall imgaug
!pip install imgaug==0.4.0
```